# Nextauth JWTDecryptionError

Tags: node.js, next.js, jwt, prisma, next-auth

I am using NextJS 13.5 with NextAuth 4.23.1. I am using the credentials provider with Prisma to login the users, I have also declared NEXTAUTH_SECRET env variable and still getting the same error.

I tried creating the variable with openssl command, but after that still the error persisted.

I have read many questions in stack but nothing worked for me.